# Importing css into jsx without Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I attempting at using the react-draft-wysiwyg npm (https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs?_k=jjqinp). I get a

> /Users/timurozkul/Documents/Repo/Others/blog/Blog/pre_app/node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css:1
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

When I follow the method on the documentation as below

[image]

How do I import css files into JSX files without web pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copy pasted the css styles from the npm into my own stylesheets. Which solved my issue. My best guess is that it is possible with Webpack and not without it because of formatting.